# Disable use of some strings by regex in TSLint?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

I sometimes see in the code constructs like this as a result of JavaScript converted to TypeScript:

```
private doSomething = function (params: IParams) {
}
```

While the correct variant is:

```
private doSomething (params: IParams) {
}
```

Former one makes it a JS function, body of which is not analyzed and is compiled as is.
Latter is checked by TypeScript compiler and if there are wrong calls to, e.g. private methods of another class, it would throw an error.

I'd like to have a rule in TSLint which would allow me to mark as erroneous strings like `(private|public|protected)\s+(.+)=\s*function`.

So, is it possible to add a rule to TSLint, may be as an existing plugin, to search for regex in strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not that easy. Tslint allows you to declare [custom rules](https://github.com/palantir/tslint#custom-rules) using [`Syntax Walkers`](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/language/walker/syntaxWalker.ts) not regular expressions.

Your rule can parse the TypeScript generated abstract syntax tree (AST):

> Given a walker, TypeScript's parser visits the AST using the visitor pattern. So the rule walkers only need to override the appropriate visitor methods to enforce its checks.

I'm not sure but you probably need the [`visitPropertyAssignment`](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/language/walker/syntaxWalker.ts#L257-L259) walker.